# Pageload with transition in ie 10

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-10

The red ul animate from 0px  to -500px on page load in IE 10. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

If I remove  the following it's not:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
li ul{position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
}
```

**Example code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>transition in ie 10</title>

<style>
li ul{-moz-transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;-o-transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;}
li ul{position:absolute;left:0;top:-500px;background:red;height:500px}
li:hover ul{top:100px;}
li{height:20px;float:left;width:100px}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
li ul{position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
}
</style>

<ul>
<li>1
<ul>
<li>2
</ul>
<li>3
<ul>
<li>4
</ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like an IE specific bug but you should be able to fix this issue by adding following CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) { 
    li ul { display: none; }    
}
```

This CSS will hide the element if browser width is more than 1300px, which is true in this case.

Here is [**working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7eYmP/10/show/), I have tested it in IE and seems to work fine to me.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some new IE bug. But it can be solved.

Grab `-ms-transition:top 0.7s ease-in-out;` from first `ul li` rule, and  place into last `ul li` into `@media` section.

You cannot place there all `transition` effects for all browsers, that will lost back-going animation in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The problem lies in that IE doesn't ignore "top:0" set in "@media screen and (max-width: 800px){}". Some how it animates from "top:0" to "top:-500px" on page load.